# Как имитировать нажатие и удерживание клавиш мыши (ПКМ и ЛКМ), а так же клавиш клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, winapi, клавиатура, хук

Здравствуйте!
Как имитировать нажатие и удерживание клавиш мыши (ПКМ и ЛКМ), а так же клавиш клавиатуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону метода [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) из `user32.dll`.

Еще на codeplex есть [исходники враппера](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com) под это все.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!